# How can I un-concatenate a bunch of files?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I accidentally made a backup of folder using "copy folder folder_backup" and got a file called folder_backup. It contains all the bits of the folder. And I accidentally deleted the folder. How do I transform file folder_backup back to the folder?

Comment: Not enough info present to answer this question, and it probably belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Your problem sounds a lot like one described here: http://superuser.com/questions/283556/folder-appears-as-a-single-file-in-windows-xp.

Comment: @bw. No, user1982779 has created a file that is the concatenation of all the files that were in his `folder` folder (in alphabetical order).